Add a frame at a fixed position in multipage report
In QGIS 3.28 I'm trying to create a multi-page report with an attribute table frame on each page. The number of pages depends on the number of points, but each should contain 40 points with some other information i.e. their coordinates. I've used a 'resize mode>use existing frames' but the tables have to be moved by hand on desired position.
Is there any way to automatically display them at a fixed page position?
I've tried to define a variable and then link it to the position, but it always moves the frame to the first page. The solution should be easily scalable depending on the number of points/pages.
